# JXDatePicker disable specific dates

Tags: java

I need to disable specific dates in JXDatePicker which I acquire from Access DB.
How can I do it?

For example, in November I want 24th and 26th to be disabled

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use setUnselectableDates() function, like this:

Date[] dates = {new date()};

jXDatePicker1.getMOnthView().setUnselectableDates(dates);

Good luck,

Evgeny.